# Перекрытие функций jQuery

Tags: jquery

Всем привет! Помогите разобраться! Есть две функции, которые конфликтуют между собой. Добавил функции **jQuery.noConflict();**, не помогло, что можно еще сделать?

Первая:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('.map').maphilight();
    });
</script>
```

Вторая:

```
<script class="example" type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery('area[alt]').qtip(
    {
        content: {
            attr: 'alt'
        },
        position: {                       
                my: 'center',
                at: 'top left',
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'ui-tooltip-tipsy ui-tooltip-shadow'
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**В HEAD подключено**

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

дальше перед каждой функцией своя библиотека.

*Перед первой*

```
<script src="jquery.maphilight.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

*перед второй*

```
<script src="jquery.qtip.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Попробуйте `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { . . .` во втором случае.

Comment: не помогло :(, все равно вторая молчит..., Если их местами менять соответственно вторая на месте первой будет работать, а уже первая на месте второй не хочет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А в чем конфликт выражается? Потому как я тут протестил и вроде бы все нормально работает.
[Посмотрите пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/GWEm6/1/).

Comment: Грамотный ответ :) Благодарю! Сайтец неплохой для отладки, только вот у меня проблема то в другом у меня две карты. С одной у меня тоже все работает, а у меня две MAP. конфликтов то вот именно никаких нету, даже firebag ничего не пишет. У меня просто не работают две функции сразу, они работают по отдельности.

Comment: Хотите две? [Их есть у меня](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/GWEm6/2/)

Comment: а так шоб одна отвечала только за подсветку а вторая только за подсказки :)

Comment: Ну, [попробуйте так](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/GWEm6/3/) Надеюсь, что это уже в точку

Comment: Благодарствую!

Answer (score 1):

Правильно ли я понимаю, что используются две библиотеки на основе jQuery? Если так, то jQuery.noConflict() не нужен. Попробуйте так:

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.maphilight.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.qtip.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
  $(".map").maphilight();

  $("area[alt]").qtip({
    content: {
      attr: "alt"
    },
    position: {             
        my: "center",
        at: "top left",
    },
    style: {
      classes: "ui-tooltip-tipsy ui-tooltip-shadow"
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Весь блок сдвинуть вниз к самому </body>

Comment: Не помогло, отрабатывает та у которой первей определена библиотека.

Comment: А с селекторами все нормально? По-отдельности работает?

Comment: да все ок, по отдельности работает, там смысл такой, вот эта jquery.maphilight.js - делает для тегов AREA подсветку, а вот эта jquery.qtip.min.js - делает всплывающую подсказку.

Comment: У меня две MAP, с первой MAP должен работать сценарий jquery.maphilight.js, как он отработает, строиться новая MAP, с ней уже работает второй сценарий по созданию всплывающих подсказок, так вот я думал он берет снова MAP и начинает с ней работать, но нет, там же четко видно, что функция выбирает элемент с классом .map, а у меня одна такая MAP с таким классом, поэтому каким то ... они пересекаются, а каким ...